# Find regions of high/low pixel density OpenCV moire patterns

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, signal-processing

I have a thresholded image of a moire pattern that looks like this (moire lines are a little bit inclined):

[image]

I want to find the x coordinate of the darkest region in the pattern (i.e., the x coordinate where in theory there is perfect overlap between two vertical lines).
[image]

By visual inspection I can easily approximate the expected x coordinate but I am not sure how to do it more precisely using computer vision automatic techniques and algorithms.

My first idea was to reduces the matrix to a vector by treating the matrix rows as a set of 1D vectors and performing the average operation on them until a single row is obtained. Then, plot this 1D array and hopefully find the x coordinate of the global minima that cooresponds to the overlap region (see [reduced_OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga4b78072a303f29d9031d56e5638da78e)).

```
reduced= cv2.reduce(threshold, 0, cv2.REDUCE_AVG)
plt.plot(reduce[0,:])
```

The obtained signal is:

[image]

The results don't look good and I don't know how to proceed from here. Any ideas on how to process the signal and extract the x coordinate are more than welcome. New ideas on how to approch this problem are also welcome.

Comment: I would go down the [Hough lines](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d6/d10/tutorial_py_houghlines.html) route. Detect lines, convert to vectors, calculate distances between vectors. Possible issues if the lines arent parallel though.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion and sorry for the late reply. I tried using [opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html) and I was not able to tune the parameters and detect all vertical lines.

Comment: I think your original approach has merit but dont use OpenCV's reduction. Convert each row to a Boolean 1D array & then check for largest continuous strings of `false` in each row` & keep track of their start and end indices (you may have more than one string per row remember). Those indices will give you the approximate column information about the bands.